# Get non-static vlaues from one class in other

Tags: android

Can you explain me, why I get 0.0 value, when I receive, for example 5 from one class in other?

```
    public class PSLServiceMain extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mLight = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
            PSLService LightSensorValue = new PSLService();
            LightSensorValue.LightSensor = 5;
           .........................
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("Wakelock")
    public class PSLService extends Service {
    ............
        float LightSensor;
      .............
     }
}
```

This is small part of the code with my question.

**EDIT**

Yep, Sorry about bad explanation.
So, I want to get Light Sensor value in my main class PSLServiceMain and send it to calss PSLService. 
The problem is that when a variable is static, its value is send to another class right. And when it is not static (instance), I get 0.0

Comment: Read up on scope, instances, and instance fields.

Comment: 5 is just for test. Non static variable show 0.0 too(

Comment: After you assign the value `5` to `LightSensorValue.LightSensor` in `onCreate`, that instance's field will have the value 5. Any other instance's will not until you do the same.

Comment: Your question is not understandable.  Just looking at your last comment, you don't have any static variables so what do you mean>?  Where are you seeing 0.0?  Please also read about Java naming conventions.  Your code is hard for experienced developers to read because you are not naming correctly.  You should also understand the difference between `Class` and `instance`.  Even your question title is hard to understand!  There is no such thing as a `non-static value` in a `Class`.  There is in an `instance`.

Comment: You should really extend what you mean, because right now your post is unreadable and ambigious, add more detail for clarity.

Comment: Your edit is a little more understandable but you still confuse `Class` and `instance`.  A static variable will be the same for all `instances` of a `class`.  A non-static variable will be different for each `instance` of the `class` so if I understand your edit correctly, you are describing normal behaviour.  You really should read some basic Java and OOP tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is what you think you're trying to achieve with this line...

```
PSLService LightSensorValue = new PSLService();
```

An Android `Service` is a special case Java class and you do not create a `Service` using `new` - instead you need to use `startService(...)` at which point the system will create the `Service` for you and call its various life-cycle methods needed to set the `Service` to a running state.

The main point is - you shouldn't be attempting to directly manipulate variables in a `Service`. If you need to pass data of some sort to a `Service` you should be doing so as extra(s) in the `Intent` used to start the `Service`.

Alternatively it is possible to bind to a `Service` and call methods using the `IBinder` interface returned when you bind to the `Service`.

EDIT: You can see how to use a bound service in the docs [Extending the Binder class](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder)

Comment: Snx for good explanation, can you please add some code with usage of `IBinder`?

Comment: @Anton : See the link I posted as an edit at the end of my answer.